# Find $x^\sqrt{2}+y^{\sqrt{2}}$ if $(\log_2 x)^4 + (\log_3 y)^4 + 8 = 8 (\log_2 x)(\log_3 y)$ and $x, y > 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Find $x^\sqrt{2}+y^{\sqrt{2}}$ if $(\log_2 x)^4 + (\log_3 y)^4 + 8 = 8(\log_2 x)(\log_3 y)$ and $x, y > 1$.

Because I do not like the logarithms, I will substitute $a = \log_2 x$ and $b = \log_3 y$. Because $x, y > 1$, we know that $a, b > 0$. We want to find $x^{\sqrt{2}}+y^{\sqrt{2}}$, so we try to get $x, y$ in terms of $a, b$. We get that $x = 2^a$ and $y = 3^b$, so what we want to find is $2^{\sqrt{2}a}+3^{\sqrt{2}b}$.

Using the equation that we are given, we get that $$a^4 + b^4 + 8 = 8ab$$ I have no idea how to continue from here, and $a, b > 0$ must be there for a reason, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: You have some typos in your problem statement and workings to correct

Comment: Can you show that there is only one solution for $(a,b)$? That will give  you the value you a re searching for. Hint: Notice that the equation in $a,b$ is symmetric with respect to the two variables.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Not OP here, but the equation in $a,b$ is a continuous plane curve with infinitely many real solutions but no integer solutions (if WA is to be trusted). --- to OP: Do you mean $y=3^b$ ?

Comment: @EricSnyder The graph of $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-8xy+8$ is a surface which intersects the plane $z=0$ in only two points.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales OIC. Hadn't thought to set the whole thing equal to some $z=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $(a,b)$ is a solution to $a^4+b^4+8=8ab$ with $b=ka$. Then $$a^4(1+k^4)-8ka^2+8=0$$
As a quadratic in $a^2$, this has discriminant $$\Delta=64k^2-32(1+k^4)=-32(k^2-1)^2$$
which is negative unless $k=\pm1$. So the only solutions have $b=\pm a$. Actually since you want $a,b>0$, they are equal. Now you just need to solve $$2a^4+8=8a^2$$ $$a^4- 4a^2+4=0$$ $$(a^2- 2)^2=0$$

And you can conclude what $a$ must be, and then what $b$ is, and then...

Comment: Alternatively $a^4+b^4+8\ge2a^2b^2+8\ge8ab$ by $u^2+v^2\ge2uv$ twice. The saturation conditions are $a^2=b^2,\,a^2b^2=4$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a cheating way, but here it goes:

We still use the substitution $a = \log_2 x$ and $b = \log_3 y$. Then, $a^4+b^4+8=8ab$. We see a $a^4$ and $b^4$, and we see a $ab$ on the other side, so we think of using AM-GM for 4 variables.

We split 8 into $4+4$ so that there are 4 terms. Applying AM-GM to the left side, $a^4 + b^4 + 4 + 4 \geq 4\sqrt[4]{(a^4)(b^4)(4)(4)}$. The right side of the inequality is equal to $8ab$, so we know that for $a, b$ to satisfy the problem condition, the equality condition of AM-GM must be satisfied. We have that $a^4=b^4=4$, or $a=b=\sqrt{2}$. We plug this into what we want to get the answer of $13$.

Comment: Alternatively, by using “completing the square” method, $0=a^4+b^4+8-8ab=(a^2-b^2)^2+2(ab-2)^2$ implies $a^2=b^2$ and $ab=2$.

Comment: Why is that "cheating"? Any solution has to show only $a=b=\sqrt{2}$ works. It may as well show otherwise $a^4+b^4+8>8ab$.